# Creating ETH Sidechains

Tags: ether, polygon, layer-2, sidechain

I have been looking online for a resource that helps me how I can build ETH sidechain and Layer 2

1. How can i use the ETH blockchain and make it a sidechain are there any tutorials or guides ?
2. Do i need to use ETH blockchain to create a Layer 2(Like Lightening Network) or this can be done using other technologies

looking forward
Thanks!